# How to use foreach and promise

Tags: javascript, foreach, promise, nested

I need to get datas with nested foreach, but I can't fill my array.
At the end of this code I would like to have an array (segId) with my datas but it is empty (because of aynschronous).
I read that I had to use Promise.all but I can't beacause my promise are nested
I'm beginner so my code is far from perfect
How can I do that ?

```
    async function getActivities(strava, accessToken)
{
  const payload = await strava.athlete.listActivities({'access_token':accessToken, 'after':'1595281514', 'per_page':'10'})
  return payload;
}
async function getActivity(strava, accessToken, id)
{
  const payload = await strava.activities.get({'access_token':accessToken, 'id':id, 'include_all_efforts':'true'})
  return payload;
}
async function getSegment(strava, accessToken, id)
{
  const payload = await strava.segments.get({'access_token':accessToken,'id':id})
  return payload
}

var tableau = []
var segId = []
const activities = getActivities(strava, accessToken)

activities.then(value => {
  value.forEach((element, index) => {
    const activity = getActivity(strava, accessToken, element['id'])
    activity.then(value => {
      value['segment_efforts'].forEach((element, index) => {
        const segment = getSegment(strava, accessToken, element['segment']['id'])
        segment.then(value => {
          segId.push(value['id'])
        })
        //console.log(segId)
      });
    });
  })
}) console.log(segId)
```

Regards
PS : Sorry for my english ...

Comment: Instead of making a ton of requests, why not fetch the data with a single request, then iterate through the data and fill the table.

Comment: Hello Teemu. Because I get the data with the Strava API. I cant get all datas with 1 request. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work. You need to always return the inner promises to include them in your promise chain. Consider splitting the code into functions to make it more readable.

```
getActivities(strava, accessToken).then(activities => {
    return Promise.all(activities.map(elem => {
        return getActivity(strava, accessToken, elem['id']).then(activity => {
            return Promise.all(activity['segment_efforts'].map(elem => {
                return getSegment(strava, accessToken, elem['segment']['id']).then(segment => {
                    segId.push(segment['id']);
                });
            }));
        })
    }));
})
.then(_ => {
    console.log(segId);
});
```

Comment: Hello Kai !! Thanks a lot !! It's not sufficient my functions getActivities, getActivity and getSegment ? How to improve that ? Regards